# SQL Error Which I Cannot Fix

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i am new to php and do not know how to fix the following error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\webareas\hj942\CW\Website\Login\incorrect.php on line 15

I have a users table with a role that consists of a normaluser and a chairperson. I am trying to only select all from the users table where the role is normaluser. I am getting the error message above. My php code is as follows:

```
<?php
include("../includes/db.php");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' And role = normaluser";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("username");
session_register("password");
header("location:myaccount.php");
}

?>
```

Thank you very much for any help provided.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer for some comments on some broader issues in your code.

Comment: @Jahed If it works now be sure to accept the answer that was the most helpful be clicking the outlined checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: If an answer was helpful, upvote it. If an answer solved your problem, also mark it as the solution. This will not only help others know what worked, but will also add to your reputation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' And role = 'normaluser'";
```

i.e: quoting the role value.
See if that works...

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), `mysql_query` can return FALSE on the occurence of an error. You should *always* check for this.

At the very least,

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

would give you an idea of what is happening.

By inspection, you have `role = normaluser` in your SQL. This should *probably* be `role = 'normaluser'`.

Finally, your code is *wide* open to an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I *STRONGLY* recommend that you read up on these, understand them and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' And role = normaluser";
```

`and role='normaluser'` - this should help. Without '' it's name of column, with it it's a string